# List of subscribed calendars via Google Calendar API

Tags: web-services, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a simple web app and what I want to achieve is to **get a list of events from one's Google Calendar**. I already managed to get together some code that reads events from the user's calendars, but I would like to also **see the events from the calendars the user is subscribed to**. I tried searching through the API documentation and googling for this, but I can't seem to find anything about it. **So, is it possible to access the information about subscribed calendars via the API v3 (or some other non-deprecated programatic way)?** Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently one can do this using https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list. Not sure why it didn't work when I tried it first...